# If a function is bounded by A and its second derivative is bounded by B, how to prove that its first derivative is bounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it true that its first derivative is bounded by $kA+B/k$ for any positive real number k?

Comment: what's the domain?

Comment: I dont think the domain matter, but if you ask, lets make it all positive real number maybe?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the domain does matter. Consider the function $Mx$ in the interval $(0,\epsilon)$, the function is bounded by $M\epsilon $ and the second derivative is $0$. The first derivative is $M$.

Comment: When you say bounded by $A$ do you mean $f(x)\leq A$ for all $x$ ?

Comment: Or do you mean $|f(x)|\leq A$ for all $x$ ?

Comment: yep, and please note that the second derivative of $f(x)$ is also bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function, such that $|f(x)|\leq A$ and $|f''(x)|\leq B$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, where $A$ and $B$ are positive constants.

We now prove $|f'(x)|\leq kA+B/k$ for all $k>0$ and $x\in \mathbb R$.

Without loss of generality suppose $f'(0)>kA+B/k$.

Notice that since $f''(x)\geq -B$ we have $f'(x)> kA+B/k -Bx$ for $x\geq0$.

Letting $w=(kA+B/k)/B$ we have:

$f(w)-f(0)=\int\limits_{0}^{(kA+B/k)/B}f'(x)dx> \int\limits_{0}^ {(kA+B/k)/B}[kA+B/k-xB] dx=(kA+B/k)^2/2B$.

Now notice $(kA+B/k)^2=k^2A^2+2AB+B^2/k^2\geq 4AB$ by AM.GM

So $\frac{(kA+B/k)^2}{2B}\geq \frac{4AB}{2B}=2A$.

We conclude $f(w)-f(0)>2A$, a contradiction, since we have $f(0)\geq -A$, which implies $f(w)>A$.

Comment: What a great answer! However I would believe that there should be more beautiful and simple proof as the problem came from a calculus textbook.

Comment: And I was wondering about the motivation of choosing the upper limit of the integral, does that come from pure cleverness?

Comment: no, it comes from noticing the graph is linear, and the slope is $B$, so it is a triangle with height $kA+B/k$ and base $(kA+B/k)/B$

Comment: BTW would you mind commenting on my method, is it rigorous? Is there any flaws?

Comment: Haha, I got your idea, when the change in x is $(kA+B/k)/B$, the change in y is maximize and is greater than 2A leading to contradiction. What a good method, I was definitely too stupid to think in this way.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I myself had come up with a proof that it is bounded, but i dont know if it is rigorous.
If we take the limit of (fx - fa)/x-a when x approach infinity for any positive number a, it will get zero due to boundedness of f. Hence according to mean value theorem, where is some number t for which the first derivative is zero. By taking a as t, there is t' greater than t with the first derivative of t' equal to zero. Therefore by induction the first derivative does not approach infinity and due to Continuity, it is bounded.

Comment: There are examples of bounded functions with non-bounded derivatives, for example $\sin(x^2)$

Comment: note that its second derivative is also bounded, so I would assume the  first derivative is continous?